# How to add label to JQuery Gantt in top left

Tags: jquery, gantt-chart

I'm using the JQuery Gantt chart from http://lp344.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/ how can I select the top left div in jquery and set it's html to add a label? I've tried to reference it as below but it didn't work:

```
$(".fn-gantt > div.spacer").html("test");
```

Comment: Which div is this and where do I find it: "top left div"?

Comment: If you go to http://lp344.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/ and scroll down you'll see the Gantt chart, if you 'Inspect' the top left grey area you should see:

Comment: Sorry (SO newbe)
<div class="gantt">
<div class="fn-gantt">
<div class="fn-content">
<div class="leftPanel">
<div class="row spacer" style="height: 72px; width: 100%;"></div>
It's this last div where I want to add html.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple to target since the class isn't used anywhere else (that I can see).

```
$(".row.spacer").html("test");
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense but I can't get it to work. Also I notice that I can set the css for .gantt eg border colour, but can't do the same for .fn-gantt, .fn-content, nor .leftPanel.

Comment: Did you try to override with `!important`?

Comment: It only works if I add my jquery code to the  onComplete : function which is part of the gantt initialisation. I can't access any properties outside ie simply within <script> tags. Seems like a scope issue. Why would that be?

Comment: Are you talking about just applying a CSS class from a stylesheet to the `div` or doing something like this: `$(".row.spacer").html("test");`? If it's the latter, the reason is almost certainly because the DOM element isn't ready before you try to apply the jQuery. If it's the former, then there's a style overriding yours. I know that using Developer Tools, I can change the CSS of that element pretty easily.